# Wordpress Page Not Rendering Properly for a small number of users

Tags: php, css, wordpress, browser

I help a friend with some dev on her wordpress powered site - http://fulltwist.net/

We installed a new theme about 3 months ago and since then she gets feedback from less than 5% of visitors saying the site doesn't render properly.

All of them say that, when viewing a single post, only the logo and the comment box show on the page - nothing else. Many say they use their phone to view it because they can't on the desktop.

I've tried load of different computers but I can't replicate the problem. I've asked them to clear their cache (hard refresh) and that hasn't helped.

I want to dig into the code but I just don't know what I'm even looking for. Can different browsers render PHP differently? I thought it was purely server side?

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this to render incorrectly? What diagnostic tools or approaches should I take?

Any points in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any idea on the user-agent? There is a lot to cover in such a broad site. 
Things you should define: 
 `User Agent/Browser`, 
`Operating System`, 
`Direct URL`,

Comment: If less than 5% *say* the site isn't rendering correctly, *at least* 5% of the users are having problems.  Maybe a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers don't render PHP, they render the HTML sent back from the server.

Look for any commonality among those with problems.  Browser, browser version, operating system.  Does the website require a plugin that some may not have or may block?  Does it render correctly with JavaScript disabled (and are complaining users disabling JavaScript / does your JavaScript run error free on their browser versions)?

You can use a service like [Gomez](http://www.gomez.com) to test your page on multiple browsers if you don't see commonality among the users.